# How can I detect a browser tab being closed in a managed BHO in IE11?

Tags: c#, .net, bho

I've created a browser helper object in C# by deriving from `IObjectWithSite`.  When `SetSite()` is called I cache the reference to the site as a `SHDocVw.WebBrowser`.  From what I've seen, IE versions prior to 11 would call `SetSite(null)` when the tab was closed, but this is no longer the case.

Is there a way of detecting when a tab is closed from managed code?

Any help much appreciated!